# How to assign price to each date after calculating difference between dates? (date_diff)

Tags: php, datediff

i am using the following code(based on this http://goo.gl/5HhSx) to calculate the difference between dates:

```
<?php
$date1 = '2012-03-29';
$date2 = '2012-04-02';
$datetime1 = date_create($date1);
$datetime2 = date_create($date2);
$interval = date_diff($datetime1, $datetime2);
echo $interval->format('%a days');
?>
```

The difference is 4 days.March has a fixed price(30€/day) and April has another(40€/day). 
Is there a way to sum the whole price? Three days until the end of march and another two from april? How can i add them correctly?
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your exact example this works:

```
$date1 = '2012-03-29';
$dateBoundary = substr($date1, 0, 8).date('t', strtotime($date1));
$date2 = '2012-04-02';
$marchPrice = 30;
$aprilPrice = 40;
$datetime1 = date_create($date1);
$datetime1Boundary = date_create($dateBoundary);
$datetime2 = date_create($date2);
$interval1 = date_diff($datetime1, $datetime1Boundary);
$interval2 = date_diff($datetime1Boundary, $datetime2);
$totalPrice = ($interval1->format('%d') * $marchPrice) + ($interval2->format('%d') * $aprilPrice);
echo number_format($totalPrice, 2);
```

You can of course extrapolate the idea for periods which span multiple months.

Comment: Yes this works as expected. So what happens if one month is divided in two periods. For example March 1st untill 15th is 20€ and from 16th until the end of the month is 30€. Should i use cases(switch-break)?

Comment: You can just set the boundary as being mid month, and alter the Price multipliers as required.

Comment: So how should i edit the boundary in order to divide the month in two periods?

Comment: Change to `$dateBoundary = '2012-03-15';`

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. Ι will try to adjust it to my needs and post the results.

Comment: Hi again. So i changed the boundaries and it works fine. I was thinking if there is a way to make date-periods? For example, low season is between 2012-11-01 to 2012-04-30, high is between 2012-07-01 to 2012-09-15 while mid-season is 2012-05-01 to 2012-06-30.

Answer (score 0):

Extract the month out of the date like this:

```
SELECT MONTH('8/14/04') as "Month";
```

for each date between '2012-03-29' and '2012-04-02' and then update the table accordingly.
In case, you want to add up the sum then use a stored procedure -declare a variable 'sum' intitialized to zero and add by using switch cases like : `CASE '04' then sum+=30 , CASE '03' then sum+=20`. Or,you can use an aggregate function too in your procedure for calculating.

Answer (score 0):

Brief logic on achieving the target result.

1. Keep an array of price list for the months,
2. find the difference of months between the dates.
3. In a loop for the month take the day difference from the last day for that month and multiply with the corresponding price from the array.
4. Inside the loop sum all this calculation into an total amount variable.

Refer the mktime() and Date() functions